# Swift Memory Crash From Selecting Image

Tags: swift, image, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have users enter a profile picture in an Enter Photo Controller as apart of registration. 90% of the time it doesn't crash when the user selects a photo from the Image Picker Controller. The error says that it's a memory error.

I thought resizing was supposed to fix the problem, yet it persists.

I am using Firestore as a backend.

Any ideas on why this is happening? I'm going insane trying to figure this out!

```
extension EnterPhotoController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    @objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        weak var selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
        let selectedImage2 = selectedImage?.resized(maxSize: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500))
        let imageButton = (picker as? CustomImagePickerController)?.imageBttn
        imageButton?.setImage(selectedImage2?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        self.imageFull = true

        dismiss(animated: true)

        self.errorLabel.text = "Registering, hang tight..."
        self.errorLabel.isHidden = false
        self.selectPhotoButton.isEnabled = false

        let filename = UUID().uuidString
        let ref = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "/images/\(filename)")
        guard let imageData = selectedImage2?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9) else { return }

        ref.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (nil, err) in
            guard err == nil else { return }
            ref.downloadURL { (url, err) in
                guard err == nil else { return }
                let imageUrl = url?.absoluteString ?? ""
                if imageUrl == "" {
                    print("fuck me man")
                }
                
                self.saveInfoToFirestore(imageUrl: imageUrl)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension UIImage {
      public func resized(maxSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
          let imageSize = self.size
          guard imageSize.height > 0, imageSize.width > 0 else { return nil }

          let ratio = min(maxSize.width/imageSize.width, maxSize.height/imageSize.height)
          let newSize = CGSize(width: imageSize.width*ratio, height: imageSize.height*ratio)

          let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: newSize)
          return renderer.image(actions: { (ctx) in
              self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
          })
      }
  }
```

And from memory (my memory) I believe this is the error. I can't reproduce it.

malloc: Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged at 0x280165460 *** Incorrect guard value: 10751132320 "app-name"(945,0x16f5df000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: You are not showing us the crash log.

Comment: I can't reproduce it :(

Comment: malloc: Heap corruption detected, free list is damaged at 0x280165460 *** Incorrect guard value: 10751132320 "app-name"(945,0x16f5df000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Comment: You have a call to `dismiss(animated: true)`. Were you intending on dismissing the `EnterPhotoController` or the photo picker?

Comment: It dismisses the photo picker. In saveInfoToFirestore function, I present the home controller.

Comment: @guywitmanyhquestion the code suggests that you're actually dismissing `EnterPhotoController`. You should call `picker.dismiss(animated: true) `. I believe your malloc_error happens on the line `saveInforToFirestore` because self is deallocated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my issue was similar, but I went crazy over figuring my issue out.  I was trying to add custom metadata with spaces in them.  So if you're adding any custom metadata, take out the spaces.  Just a possibility this is your problem, I can't see your upload code.